# nco, reduce dim, netcdf

Tags: netcdf, nco

I have a netcdf file

```
dimensions:
        lsmlat = 1400 ;
        lsmlon = 2800 ;
        time = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
        lsmpft = 1 ;
variables:
        double LATIXY(lsmlat, lsmlon) ;
                LATIXY:long_name = "latitude" ;
                LATIXY:units = "degrees north" ;
        double LONGXY(lsmlat, lsmlon) ;
                LONGXY:long_name = "longitude" ;
                LONGXY:units = "degrees east" ;
```

I want the variables as

```
double LATIXY(lsmlat) ;
            LATIXY:long_name = "latitude" ;
            LATIXY:units = "degrees north" ;
    double LONGXY(lsmlon) ;
            LONGXY:long_name = "longitude" ;
            LONGXY:units = "degrees east" ;
```

so that the file can be read in GIS.
Any nco command is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original file has the structure of a curvilinear grid, where both lat and lon arrays are 2-D. Your desired grid is rectangular, where both lat and lon are 1-D. The only way to do this, in general, is to regrid. The NCO operator [ncremap](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncremap) does regridding...